# form submission to a directory? Possible?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, action

I know it might sound a little stupid here. But i downloaded a script off github and realise that one of its form submission actually reference the form inputs to a folder/dir instead of a single php file.

My question here now is if this is the case, does it mean that all the scripts within the folder itself will be able to get my $_POST form inputted results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about something like:

```
<form method='post' action='some/directory'>
```

It expects that the file served by the web server as the directory index (e.g. `index.php`) receives the form post and handles the input.   So you aren't posting the form to a directory, but to the default file the web server executes when the directory is accessed.

The `action=` attribute of a `<form>` tag just needs to be some relative or absolute URI - it doesn't have to point to an actual existing file. It would be up to the web server to determine which script to execute based on directory index rules, rewrite rules, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> its form submission actually reference the form inputs to a folder/dir

In HTTP URIs there is no such thing. All URIs will point to a resource. It is up to the server to decide how to respond to that resource.

Something that looks like a directory in a URI might map on to a real directory on a file system. Web servers will typically use something like a `DirectoryIndex` directive to use a default file.

It might map onto a file at several levels above, and then be handled by that: `http://example.com/foo.php/bar/baz/` with `foo.php` reading `/bar/baz/` from the URI and doing something with it.

It might have an explicit mapping (e.g. with the `ScriptAlias` directive) that internally maps it onto another script.

It might have a programatic mapping (e.g. with mod_rewrite) that uses regular expressions to map it onto something else (perhaps breaking the 'directories' into different query string paramaters).

There are many other possibilities.

> My question here now is if this is the case, does it mean that all the scripts within the folder itself will be able to get my $_POST form inputted results?

In theory, it would be possible to configure a server in such a way that a POST request is passed onto every script in a directory on a file system and then a composite response returned. I've never seen anyone try that (or want to try that) though. One of the above explanations is far more likely.